# css transition not working in firefox properly

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-transitions

Basically I've an HTML 5 `range` element, which works as my app videos tracker.
Before mentioning my problem here is CSS stylesheet:

```
.vidskb_r::-moz-range-thumb,.vidskb_r::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    -moz-transition: height .2s ease-in-out, width .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    transition: height .2s ease-in-out, width .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: height .2s ease-in-out, width .2s ease-in-out;
    background-color:rgb(213,90,0);
}
input[type=range]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb,input[type=range]:hover::-moz-range-thumb{
    height:12px; 
    width:12px;
}
```

Now `.vidskb_r::-moz-range-thumb,.vlrange::-moz-range-thumb,` doesn't let me create my custom range thumb as long as I create a new specific class for my thumb:

```
.vidskb_r::-moz-range-thumb{
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    border-radius:50px;
    background-color:rgb(213,90,0);
    -moz-transition: height .2s ease-in-out, width .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: height .2s ease-in-out, width .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Reason: I don't know.

And Also the transition doesn't works too, when I hover over the range, it just pop up and not with animation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a bunch of custom vendor prefixes (`-webkit-transition`, `-o-transition`, `-ms-transition`, `-moz-transition`, `-webkit-transform`, `-o-transform`, `-ms-transform` etc.) which I'm not sure you need at the tail-end of 2016.

Comment: Note also, that where you _do_ need vendor prefixes (eg. `-moz-appearance`) the non-prefixed style comes **last** - so that if the standard is supported it will override the proprietary implementation.

Comment: @rounin well `transition` works for animating the thumb `height & width` which change the position of thumb a little so I had to use `transform` to make thumb repositioned.

Comment: To help fixing a non working code, we need a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue

Comment: @LGSon You said minimal code right? I edited my question and removed all !important code.